# How to use each array value on each for cycle (Same quantity)

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have the following **array** called **equipos_seleccionados**

```
["12 - v4", "100 - v500"]
```

**This is how the frontend looks:**

[image]

As you can see, i automatically generate as many textbox as the value on inputs on the head section.

**GOAL**: I would like to use (on this case) the value **12 - v4** to the first 2 elements (Selects) and the value **100 - v500** for the next 4 elements (Selects).

**This is the code i have so far:**

```
result["cantidad_seriado"].forEach(function(entry) {

    for (var i = 0; i < entry; i++) {

        div_hr1.append("<select class='form-control' id='selected_equipo_seriado' name='selected_equipo_seriado' required='required' disabled><option selected value=''>" + equipos_seleccionados + "</option></select><br>");

        div_hr2.append(`

      <input class="form-control" id="nro_serie_seriado" name="nro_serie_seriado" type="number" required="required" placeholder="Nro de serie"><br>
        
    `);

    };

    div_hr1.append(`

      <hr class="sidebar-divider" style="border-color:blue;">

    `);

    div_hr2.append(`

      <hr class="sidebar-divider" style="border-color:blue;">

    `);

});**
```

**This is how it should looks:**

[image]

Comment: What is "cantidad_seriado" ? is it an array or a dictionary?

Comment: @RigobertoRamirezCruz thanks for your answer, its an array who store the quantity column (Cantidad), on this case it's: ["2", "3"]

Comment: In the same order as presented, right? I mean, that 2 is for 12 - v4, and the 3 is for 100 - v500 according to the example your provided.

Comment: @RigobertoRamirezCruz exactly! 2 and 3 are the numbers that i need to generate that amount of rows (Selects and Inputs). On the first two selects i need  12 - v4 and the next three 100 - v500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print just the element in **equipos_seleccionados** that is in the same position as **result["cantidad_seriado"]** via the overload that uses the index of the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function.

You just need to change the `.forEach(function(entry))` for `.forEach(function(entry, index))`

```js
var equipos_seleccionados = ["12 - v4", "100 - v500"]
div_hr1 = document.getElementById('div_hr1')
div_hr2 = document.getElementById('div_hr2')

var result = ["2", "3"]

result.forEach(function(entry, index) {

  console.log(entry)
    for (var i = 0; i < entry; i++) {

        div_hr1.innerHTML += "<select class='form-control' id='selected_equipo_seriado' name='selected_equipo_seriado' required='required' disabled><option selected value=''>" + equipos_seleccionados[index] + "</option></select><br>"

        div_hr2.innerHTML += `

      <input class="form-control" id="nro_serie_seriado" name="nro_serie_seriado" type="number" required="required" placeholder="Nro de serie"><br>
        
    `

    }

    div_hr1.innerHTML += `

      <hr class="sidebar-divider" style="border-color:blue;">

    `

    div_hr2.innerHTML += `

      <hr class="sidebar-divider" style="border-color:blue;">

    `

});
```

```html
<div id="div_hr1" style="width=50%; display:inline-block;"></div>
<div id="div_hr2" style="width=50%; display:inline-block;"></div>
```

This works when both of your arrays come in the same order, in this case "2" is for "12 - v4" and "3" for "100 - v500". If you don't want to depend on the order of the items in both arrays you can use a dictionary based structure instead of that array, so you can have something like this:

```js
var quantityPerEquipment = { "12 - v4": 2, "100 - v500": 3 }

var equipos_seleccionados = ["12 - v4", "100 - v500"]
div_hr1 = document.getElementById('div_hr1')
div_hr2 = document.getElementById('div_hr2')

Object.keys(quantityPerEquipment).forEach(function(entry) {

  console.log(entry)
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityPerEquipment[entry]; i++) {

        div_hr1.innerHTML += "<select class='form-control' id='selected_equipo_seriado' name='selected_equipo_seriado' required='required' disabled><option selected value=''>" + entry + "</option></select><br>"

        div_hr2.innerHTML += `

      <input class="form-control" id="nro_serie_seriado" name="nro_serie_seriado" type="number" required="required" placeholder="Nro de serie"><br>
        
    `

    }

    div_hr1.innerHTML += `

      <hr class="sidebar-divider" style="border-color:blue;">

    `

    div_hr2.innerHTML += `

      <hr class="sidebar-divider" style="border-color:blue;">

    `

});
```

```html
<div id="div_hr1" style="width=50%; display:inline-block;"></div>
<div id="div_hr2" style="width=50%; display:inline-block;"></div>
```

That will ensure that your elements always match.